# Is there a way to add a placeholder for this type?

Tags: typescript

Obligatory: apologies if this has been asked before!

I'm working on a React Native project and would like to add a placeholder for the screen name:

```
type HomeNavProps = BottomTabNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  "Home"
>
```

Ideally, I'd like something more generic like:

```
type NavProps<T> = BottomTabNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  T
>
```

So I can then use it like:

```
const { navigate } = useNavigation<NavProps<"Home">>()
```

Granted I'm not sure how to do it, but when I try the above, I just get:

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof RootStackParamList'.
```

For reference, `RootStackParamList` is:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined
  Levels: undefined
  Map: undefined
  MyBadges: undefined
  MyImpact: undefined
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain `T` to the correct type. This would be the same type as its expected destination.

In this case I believe that would be: `keyof RootStackParamList`

```
type NavProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> = BottomTabNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  T
>
```